# Sort array of objects by given incomplete array of orders in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, object

I have an array of objects:

```
var items = [
   {
      "id":"sugar",
      "type": 'eatables'
   },
   {
      "id":"petrol",
      "type": 'utility'
   },
   {
      "id":"apple",
      "type": 'fruits'
   },
   {
      "id":"mango",
      "type": 'fruits'
   },
   {
      "id":"book",
      "type": 'education'
   }
];
```

Now I have another array of orders with the help of which I want to sort `items` array:

```
var orders = [
   {
      "id":"sugar",
      "order":5
   },
   {
      "id":"book",
      "order":1
   }
];
```

Now what I am trying so far in my logic is that I am putting so many loops that it is totally creating mess.

Can anyone suggest me with a short and optimized logic for this?

Comment: What happens with the other elements of the array ?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut they remains in the same sequence as before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach could be creating one *dictionary* which will keep the `order` for every element. Also, I've iterated the whole `items` array to store the *position* for the elements that are not in the `orders` array.

First of all, I'll *declare* one *array* which keep the whole *orders*, thus one array with `1..N` elements.

```
var orderNumbers = Array.from({length: items.length}, (_, v) => v + 1);
```

Then I started to create the dictionary by iterating `orders` array and remove *orders* from `orderNumbers`.

The last step is iterating the *items* array and use `shift` method to `"pop"` the first element.

The final *dictionary* will look like

```
{
  "sugar": 2,
  "book": 3,
  "petrol": 1,
  "apple": 4,
  "mango": 5
}
```

In this code I used one *dictionary* because its `lookup` has *complexity* of `O(1)`.

```js
var items = [ { "id":"sugar", "type": 'eatables' }, { "id":"petrol", "type": 'utility' }, { "id":"apple", "type": 'fruits' }, { "id":"mango", "type": 'fruits' }, { "id":"book", "type": 'education' } ], orders = [ { "id":"sugar", "order":2 }, { "id":"book", "order":3 } ], orderNumbers = Array.from({length: items.length}, (_, v) => v + 1);

var ordersDict = orders.reduce((acc, item) => { 
     acc[item.id] = item.order;
     
     //remove from order numbers
     let index = orderNumbers.findIndex(el => el == item.order);
     orderNumbers.splice(index, 1);
     
     return acc;
}, {});

for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
  if(!ordersDict.hasOwnProperty(items[i].id)){
    ordersDict[items[i].id] = orderNumbers[0];
    orderNumbers.shift();
   }
}

//sort the array
items.sort((a,b) => ordersDict[a.id] - ordersDict[b.id]);

console.log(items);
```

Comment: Yeah now its working perfect. I am accepting your answer. But can we do something more to optimize the logic or reduce the line of code and stuff...

Comment: @StormTrooper, I have updated my answer. That's why I used a dictionary, because the lookup has complexity of `O(1)` and I tried to avoid `find` function everytime.

Answer (score 0):

```
let oorder = new Object();

orders.map(item=>{oorder[item.id]=item.order});

var new_items = [];

items.map(item=>{new_items[oorder[item.id]-1]=item});
```